# Как сделать выпадающий список с помощю Listview

Tags: listview

Вопрос, на который я нигде не нашел ответ. Касается события в `ListView onItemClickListener`. В качестве адаптера использую `simpleCursorAdapter`. Мне нужно сгенерировать график платежей, по нажатию на `item` нужно найти во `view` нажатого пункта списка спрятанный `layout` с атрибутом `Visibility:gone` и сделать его видимым. То есть типа выпадающий пояснительный список. Вот код

```
@Override

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
            long id) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LinearLayout lsubitem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lsubitem);

        if (lsubitem.getVisibility() == View.GONE) { 
            lsubitem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {

            lsubitem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

Загвоздка вот в чем.

1. Допустим сгенерировалось 50 пунктов в `listview`, из них 10 помещается на экране. Когда я нажимаю на какой-либо пункт, например, 1-ый пункт, то он делает видимыми и 11, 21, 31, 41 - пункты. Почему так происходит?
2. Также если резко прокрутить вниз или вверх список, то сбивается порядок. То есть выбрал я 1ый пунк - открылись помимо 1 еще 11, 21, 31 и т.д потом прокрутил резко вниз и они стали 3, 13, 23, 33 и т.д.

Comment: потому что нужно обновлять в getView и подобных методах. ListView кеширует элементы, когда Вы прокручиваете, то те элементы, которые "ушли с поля видимости" подсовываются с другой стороны. Если в getView их не обновить правильно (не обновить все поля), то они будут в "странном состоянии".

Вывод. onItemClick должен указывать адаптеру новое состояние и вызывать обновление списка (notifyDataChange).

Comment: буду очень признателен, если Вы меня еще немного направите к решению задачи) примерчик какой-нибудь, например

Comment: подумал немного над решением. Создайте два различных layout - один у Вас уже есть - это базовый, и второй - расширенный, с дополнительными контролами (можно и один в принципе создать, просто часть скрыть). У элементов, которые хранятся в адаптере, заведите спецполе типа bool - expand. Если оно false - показывайте обычный layout, в противном случае - большой (это метод getView).

в `onItemClick` просто переключайте это поле и вызывайте `notifyDataSetChanged()` у адаптера. Этот метод сам обновит listView.

Comment: @KoVadim Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно при нажатии на ячейку списка передавать в `getView()` позицию нажатой ячейки. А в `getView()` сравнивать вашу позицию которую вы передали с позицией которая вызывается в `getView()`, после пишите ваш код.

```
if (lsubitem.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
    lsubitem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else 
    lsubitem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```